# Got error about 'AD_SERVICES_CONFIG' when uploading App bundle to google play console

Tags: android, react-native

the detailed error message is below, any ideas, many thanks.

```
Your app is not allowed to specify 'AD_SERVICES_CONFIG' property in the manifest.
```

I tried to add permissions to the manifest, but still got the same error.
https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup-api-access

Answer (score 4):

If you are using unity - Appears to be a bug in 4.7.0, use the next version up.

implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.7.1'

Comment: This worked for me. I was updating all my admob adapters and ended up having to declare 4.7.1 to upload successfully.
```implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:4.7.0.0'```